# Saving the output of a function as a new dataf.frame and using the name of the original input in the saving name

Tags: r, function, dataframe, save, output

I've written a function that takes the top 50 results from a list based on ranks.

```
myfunction <- function(x){

...selects the top 50 results

return(the top 50 results)
```

If you need the exact function I can add more detail.

Ideally, what I would like the function to do is save the top 50 list as a new data.frame by automatically including the name of the input like this:

'x'_top_50

So I can repeatedly use the function and it automatically save the output for use later.

Any help would be great, thank you!

*EDIT*

This is what I have from the first answer:

```
t50<-function(x){
m101mb<-x[,1:2]
m101ts<-x[,3:4]
incommon<-intersect(m101mb$mb_gs,m101ts$ts_gs)
df1<-m101mb[m101mb$mb_gs %in% incommon,]
df2<-m101ts[m101ts$ts_gs %in% incommon,]
df3<-df1[order(df1$mb_gs),]
df4<-df2[order(df2$ts_gs),]
df5<-cbind(df3,df4)
df6<-data.frame(df5$mb_rank,df5$ts_rank)
df7<-rowMeans(df6)
df8<-data.frame(df5,df7)
df9<-data.frame(df8$ts_gs,df8$df7)
df10<-df9[order(df9$df8.df7),]
colnames(df10)<-c("Gene_symbol","Gene_rank")
assign(paste(deparse(substitute(x)),"top", "50", sep = "_"), df10[1:50,])
return(df10[1:50,])
}
```

But it still wont save as a new variable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want is the function `assign()` to assign the dataframe with a specific name; and `deparse()` and `subsitute()` to extract the previously given variable name.

```
myfunction <- function(x){

  #whatever you're doing it's here that results in the_top_50_results as a dataframe

  assign(paste(deparse(substitute(x)), "top", "50", sep = "_"), the_top_50_results, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for such a quick reply! I think I understand the logic of the code but not quite sure how to implement it in the function. I'll add and edit to my original question to show you what I mean.

Comment: Added an `envir` argument to make sure the variable is assigned to the global environment. I forgot to add and it made the dataframe assigned within the function scope, not the global scope. I hope this clears up.